# SQL to LINQ query equivalent

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Hello I need to crate linq query from this SQL:

**SQL:**

```
select 
   p.id, 
   p.Name, 
   sum(h.Hour) 
from 
   dbo.Hour h 
INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectView p ON h.ProjectId = p.Id 
WHERE 
   h.PeopleId = 7999 
group by 
   p.Name, p.Id
```

**LINQ:** I tried this but it is not the same:

```
    var query = from hours in _hourRepository.GetAll()
                join proj in _projectRepository.GetAll() on hours.ProjectId equals proj.Id
                where hours.PeopleId == personId
                group hours by new { proj.Id, proj.Name, proj.Flag, hours.Hours } into g
                select new PopleProjectsSumDto
                {
                    Id = g.Key.Id,
                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                    Flag = g.Key.Flag,
                    Hours = g.Sum(h => h.Hours)
                };
```

OK i find **solution** by removing hours from group:

**LINQ:**

```
    var query = from hours in _hourRepository.GetAll()
                join proj in _projectRepository.GetAll() on hours.ProjectId equals proj.Id
                where hours.PeopleId == personId
                group hours by new { proj.Id, proj.Name, proj.Flag } into g
                select new PopleProjectsSumDto
                {
                    Id = g.Key.Id,
                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                    Flag = g.Key.Flag,
                    Hours = g.Sum(h => h.Hours)
                };
```

Comment: why did you add flag to join group in your linq query?

Comment: I think problem is in Hours grouping in LINQ, becouse when hours are different values 12, 15 it returns 2 rows, but when the same value 15,15 it return one row with SUM 30..

Comment: can you update your question and show your data?